# jQuery detect when content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an ajax filter, which is replacing a container on the page.
After the content is appended to the DOM I need to foreach each block of the newly appended content and get the height of it and then set each of them with max height.
Here is the tricky part.When the content is appended the images are not loaded, so I cannot calculate accurately the height of the whole block.
Here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(html) {
    $('#product-pagination-container').html(html);
    adjustBoxHeights();

    //Sroll to products
    /*
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#product-pagination-container').offset().top},
        'slow');
    */
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err.responseText);
  }
});

function adjustBoxHeights() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.product-grid > div, .content-top .product-layout > div, .content-bottom .product-layout > div').each(function(){
    $(this).height('auto');
    if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) {maxHeight = $(this).height()}
  });
  $('.product-grid > div, .content-top .product-layout > div, .content-bottom .product-layout > div').each(function(){
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
  });
}
```

A working solution is to run adjustBoxHeights after certain timeout, but I dont like it.

Comment: Do it after a timeout of tot secs

Comment: Have you had a look at Promise objects?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno That's never going to be a reliable solution because changes on the server could make the image not available, no matter how long you wait or changes in network speed could make the time selected for the delay incorrect.

Comment: In that case they'll never load

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Not in the second case that I mentioned. In that case, a fixed timeout will occur before the images have loaded.

Comment: You aren't wrong but anyway he can calculate again the height everytime that an image is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of the HTML that is being appended into the DOM, you can give the image elements a common class name and then set up a `load` event callback for elements belonging to that class. You would do this in your AJAX "success" callback.

In the subsequent `load` event handlers, you would then get the `height` of the appropriate parent/ancestor element.

Assuming the images coming in from the AJAX call all belonged to the `img` class, it would be basically this:

```js
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(html) {
    $('#product-pagination-container').html(html);
    
    // Now, that the DOM has been updated to inlcude the new images, we can 
    // find them in the DOM and set up a load event callback for each:
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img")).forEach(function(pic){
      // As each images finishes loading, adjust the box heights:
      pic.addEventListener("load", adjustBoxHeights);
    });
    

    //Sroll to products
    /*
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#product-pagination-container').offset().top},
        'slow');
    */
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err.responseText);
  }
});

function adjustBoxHeights() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.product-grid > div, .content-top .product-layout > div, .content-bottom .product-layout > div').each(function(){
    $(this).height('auto');
    if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) {maxHeight = $(this).height()}
  });
  $('.product-grid > div, .content-top .product-layout > div, .content-bottom .product-layout > div').each(function(){
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
  });
}
```

Comment: I did it, but using jQuery.